# MFCC with Java Linear and Logarithmic Filters

Tags: java, algorithm, matlab, signal-processing, mfcc

I am implementing MFCC algorithm with Java. There is a sample code for triangular filters and MFCC at Java. Here is the link: [MFCC Java](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3abLs8E-GgsSEJ%3acollaborate.d2labs.org/plugins/scmsvn/viewcvs.php/%2acheckout%2a/Source%2520Code/Trunk/Software/Brailletutor/dsp/featureExtraction.java?root=brallie062bex%20param%20inputSignal%20Speech%20Waveform%20%2816%20bit%20integer%20data%29%20filetype%3ajava&cd=1&hl=tr&ct=clnk&gl=tr&source=www.google.com.tr) However I should follow that code written in Matlab: [MFCC Matlab](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/muscontent/practical/mfcc.m)

My question is that **at Matlab code it talks about linear and logarithmic filters however there is nothing about that at Java code**. I should measure the performance of logarithmic 
and linear filters but I implemented that Java code and there is nothing about that. Also I didn't understand what these fbins and cbins at Java code?

Comment: did you get the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The Java code does include a non linear transformation, basically mapping your linear frequency scale to the mel-scale. 'cbins' refer to the center (frequency) of each filter bank.

The Java code is exactly what an MFCC code should look like. So, it should work well for you.